# External ip address being treated as local (ARP asking for external IP's address)

Tags: routing, router, arp, openwrt, packetloss

I am using a virtual machine with OpenWRT for routing, on a Linux machine (Slackware). I am trying to configure a host only interface (eth0) as the wan interface. eth1 is Ethernet attached as a bridge interface.

I tried to test the configuration pinging to an external ip address (from OpenWRT).

```
# ping -I eth0 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

I used wireshark and i saw the system (OpenWRT side) is sending ARP request asking for the mac address of 8.8.8.8. What is going on? It looks that the gateway is being ignored.

My route:

```
# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.56.1    0.0.0.0         UG    1      0        0 eth0
default         192.168.56.1    0.0.0.0         UG    5      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.56.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     5      0        0 eth0
```

Iptables is configure to accept all packets for input, output and forward.

More tests:

```
# ping -I eth0 192.168.56.1
PING 192.168.56.1 (192.168.56.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.56.1: seq=0 ttl=64 time=10.000 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.56.1: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.000 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.56.1: seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.000 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.56.1: seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.000 ms
^C
--- 192.168.56.1 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.000/2.500/10.000 ms
```

.

```
# ip route show
default via 192.168.56.1 dev eth0  proto static  metric 1 
default via 192.168.56.1 dev eth0  proto static  metric 5 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.1 
192.168.56.0/24 dev eth0  proto static  scope link  metric 5
```

Comment: It would be useful to include the output of `arp -n` and a packet capture showing the ARP requests.

Comment: `I am trying to configure a host only interface (eth0) as the wan interface` - Why do you have a default route configured on the **host only** interface (eth0)?  Have you confused your interface names in the question perhaps?  Is eth0 the bridged interface and eth1 the host-only interface?  Which subnet is supposed to be the **host-only** subnet?

Comment: @Zoradache No, the information is correct. Diagram: Bridged Ethernet (eth1 192.168.0.0/24) - Host only adapter (eth0 192.168.56.0/24) - Internet (Host machine). How would the VM reach internet without a default route? For more information, in the host machine packets from host only adaptor are forwarded to different usb wlan interfaces, which I cant attach because they freeze if they get accidentally disconnected (from cable or wireless network) and I have to restart VM to connect again.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have your default route set to the device and not to your gateway IP. Check `ip route show` for a default line without a "via IP" part.

EDIT: sorry, I now see your route output. However, `ip route show` is more helpful as there are routing details that can't be shown by the route command. Also it's strange that there are apparently 2 default routes that are the same, hopefully ip will show the difference.

Comment: Updated. About two default routes - one is added by openwrt automatically but I added a permanent one because sometimes openwrt fails to add it.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to reinstall OpenWRT on the virtual machine but didnt solve the problem.

After some configurations on the host machine (routes and iptables) the problem disappeared. I'm sad I couldnt identify the exact cause for this problem. It looks there was a loop (packet send by router was received again by the router) because a misconfiguration on the host machine and that was causing the problem somehow.

I'll edit this answer if it happens again and I get more details.

Comment: That could be that wrong route was there *in the past*, and then the remains of it were left in the route *cache*.